# How to deal with papers on which Allah's name is mentioned?

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, names

What is the sharia's ruling about personal names found in newspapers etc that include either the Prophet's name or Allah's name (Abdullah, AbdulHadi,Muhammad Qasim). How may these papers be disposed of or destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

Islamic scholars have mentioned three ways to dispose of papers on which Allah or Quranic Ayat are mentioned:

1. These papers should be collected and buried by digging a deep hole.
2. These papers should be collected and put in a cloth bag, adding weight in it and throwing them in running river or canal so that they can go deep in water.
3. There are a few organizations which are doing the noble cause to handle this. For this purpose they place some small containers at prominent places to collect them and transport them to specified place. This option can also be availed.